Where not in query error invalid input syntax for type bigint typeorm
I was working on a project and i need to use "where not in" query like this
return manager
  .getRepository(SlideshowItemEntity)
  .createQueryBuilder('slideshow_items')
  .softDelete()
  .where('image_id NOT IN (:imageIDs)', { imageIDs: imageIDs.join(',') })
  .andWhere('slideshow_id = :slideshowID', { slideshowID: slideshowID })
  .execute();

but when i run the query it returns error
invalid input syntax for type bigint: "1,2,3"

how can i solve this?
i want to delete all slideshow items except some with image_id 1,2,3
my database is postgresql and i am using nestjs and typeorm
thanks for any answers.

I'm guessing that the query manager is putting quotes around 1,2,3 because it's a string.  It might be smart enough to just handle the plain list by itself.  Try that.

Not familiar with TypeORM but you might be able to use NOT =ANY(). ANY() takes an array as input

.where('image_id NOT IN (:...imageIDs)', { imageIDs })

or you can look for the syntax in here.
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder
